# How can I repeat a number cycle using mod operator?

Tags: c++, modulo

I have to loop through `1 <= i <= 20` and every time I mod any i, I want to get a value between `1,2,3`. Sorry I have not found any useful resources online. That's why I posted it here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what mod does? Do you know how to get any interesting result applying it to `i`?

Comment: Use the modulo operator, e.g. index = (i % 3)+1; (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/arithmetic-operators/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ the `%` sign acts as [the remainder operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators).

If you do

```cpp
i % 3;
```

The possible values are `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Using that as a starting point, we can shift by `1`:

```cpp
(i % 3) + 1;
```

The possible values are now `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Comment: Minor point: `%` is the **remainder** operator, not the modulo operator. Remainders can be negative.